# Which one is good Java or Json in GWT client?

Tags: java, json, gwt

I have a GWT client project and REST is my web service. I have a class Student and I want to save it in data base which is in web service. I am converting student to json and sending to Server. Is it right method? My doubt is In client side am I have to use Json object instead of Student?(because it will not need any conversion for sending to server) And if i am using Json it will give good performance like java?

Comment: If you are still confused between `java` and `javascript` and  `json` then probably its not the right time yet to ask this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or JavaScript Object Notation, is a text-based open standard designed for human-readable data interchange.

So if you are using it to transfer data between your rest service and GWT front-end then its fine.
To save Student JSON notation you can convert it to POJO using many available library like [jersey](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html) or [GWTJsonizer](http://code.google.com/p/acris/wiki/GWTJsonizer)and can store easily that to DB.

To summarise. JSON and Java object are two different things, use JSON to transfer information,
convert JSON to java object and use this java object for further processing in you web service

Comment: My doubt is I want java class to bind with GWT components(Student). Can I create a model using json for binding with Gwt components instead of student.? Means is it right if i am making a model using json like student?

Answer (score 0):

Json (in this case) is used to serialize your student object. This means that it is used to pick out the parts of your student object that differentiate it from other objects (such as name, age, sex ...) in order to transport this information elsewhere. If you won't be needing the student object server-side then fine, just dump it into the db. On the client side however you should have a class or method that creates json objects from student objects and also creates student objects from json objects. **Do not treat a json object as a student object**